# IPhone Google Location API V3 get all near location from current position

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

how to get all near location from passing current location lat & log to google location api ?

i have registered google location api and created url to fetch all near location , but the problem is at a time i am only able to pass one "types" e.g types = atm

i want to pass multiple types like  "atm|bar|cafe|florist|park" so that i can able to get all the information by passing single request.

below is url which i am passing

URL : https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=23.025651,72.507753&radius=4754796&types=bar|cafe&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyDtsmfnmSKSgDGK4s5

But by passing spurted by "|" it will give no records , by passing single type only it will provide full details.

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: What response do you get?

Comment: by saprating | it providing null response , but by passing single type =atm it giving me full details of atm near to my location.

Comment: No error message and status in the response?

Comment: No error msg or status :(

Comment: From the documentation: *radius — Defines the distance (in meters) within which to return place results. The maximum allowed radius is 50 000 meters.* You are asking for a radius of 4754 km.

Comment: Thanks MrUpsidown , by reducing the radius by 25000 meters , it responcing with below error with two tag "bar|cafe",

error : Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'

Comment: What if you test the URL in your browser? I don't have much experience with iOS.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to request the multiple types for Place API V3 , below is the code by which we can request multiple types and get all near location information.

```
currentCentre.latitude = 23.025651;
currentCentre.longitude = 72.507753;

NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=%f,%f&radius=%@&types=atm|food&sensor=true&key=%@", currentCentre.latitude, currentCentre.longitude, [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", 1000], kGOOGLE_API_KEY];


NSURL *googleRequestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[url
                                    stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


// Retrieve the results of the URL.
dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: googleRequestURL];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
});
```

From the FetchedData we will get the JSON Response from google and we can able to get all details of requested different types in single request.

Thanks.